# I can't figure out how to pass attributes from a csv file into a class and then print a specific attribute from said class

Tags: python, csv, class

I am very new to python and I am attempting to pass attributes from a csv file into a class and then I'm trying to print a specific attribute from that class.

This was my attempt, but I realize that I am pretty far off from a correct solution.

```
import csv

class Pokemon:
    def __init__(self, name, type1, type2, Atk, Def, SpAtk, SpDef, Spd, Health):
        self.name = name
        self.type1 = type1
        self.type2 = type2
        self.Atk = Atk
        self.Def = Def
        self.SpAtk = SpAtk
        self.SpDef = SpDef
        self.Spd = Spd
        self.Health = Health

    def pokeprint(self):
        print(f"{self.Atk}")

Pokemon_list = []

with open('Pokemon.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None)
    for row in reader:
        Pokemon_list.append(Pokemon(row[0], row[1], row[2], int(row[3]), int(row[4]), int(row[5]), int(row[6]), int(row[7]), int(row[8])))

pokeprint(Bulbasaur)
```

Here are a couple lines from the csv file:

```
Bulbasaur,Grass,Poison,45,49,49,65,65,45
Ivysaur,Grass,Poison,60,62,63,80,80,60
Venusaur,Grass,Poison,80,82,83,100,100,80
```

Comment: You never assigned the variable `Bulbasaur`. You need something like `Bulbasaur = Pokemon_list[0]`. You can also loop over the list, looking for the one with `item.name == 'Bulbasaur'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to create a dictionary of pokemons where keys are names of pokemons and values are instances of class `Pokemon`. For example:

```py
import csv

class Pokemon:
    def __init__(self, name, type1, type2, Atk, Def, SpAtk, SpDef, Spd, Health):
        self.name = name
        self.type1 = type1
        self.type2 = type2
        self.Atk = Atk
        self.Def = Def
        self.SpAtk = SpAtk
        self.SpDef = SpDef
        self.Spd = Spd
        self.Health = Health

    def pokeprint(self):
        print(f"{self.Atk}")

Pokemon_dct = {}

with open('data.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        Pokemon_dct[row[0]] = Pokemon(row[0], row[1], row[2], int(row[3]), int(row[4]), int(row[5]), int(row[6]), int(row[7]), int(row[8]))

Pokemon_dct['Bulbasaur'].pokeprint()
```

Prints:

```
45
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be for each Pokemon class instance to maintain a dictionary representing the columns and associated values from the CSV file.

Override __str__ such that it returns the string representation of the instance's dictionary.

Overrid both __getitem__ and __getattr__ to give convenient mechanisms for acquiring individual column data.

Given a CSV file that looks like:

```
name,type1,type2,Atk,Def,SpAtk,SpDef,Spd,Health
Bulbasaur,Grass,Poison,45,49,49,65,65,45
Ivysaur,Grass,Poison,60,62,63,80,80,60
Venusaur,Grass,Poison,80,82,83,100,100,80
```

...then...

```
import csv

FILENAME = 'Pokemon.csv'

class Pokemon():
    def __init__(self, _dict):
        self._dict = _dict
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._dict)
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._dict.get(key)
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self._dict.get(key)

Pokemon_list = []

with open(FILENAME, newline='', encoding='UTF-8') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    columns = next(reader)
    for line in reader:
        pc = Pokemon(dict(zip(columns, line)))
        Pokemon_list.append(pc)
        print(pc)
        print(pc['Atk']) # getitem
        print(pc.Atk) # getattr
```

**Output:**

```
{'name': 'Bulbasaur', 'type1': 'Grass', 'type2': 'Poison', 'Atk': '45', 'Def': '49', 'SpAtk': '49', 'SpDef': '65', 'Spd': '65', 'Health': '45'}
45
45
{'name': 'Ivysaur', 'type1': 'Grass', 'type2': 'Poison', 'Atk': '60', 'Def': '62', 'SpAtk': '63', 'SpDef': '80', 'Spd': '80', 'Health': '60'}
60
60
{'name': 'Venusaur', 'type1': 'Grass', 'type2': 'Poison', 'Atk': '80', 'Def': '82', 'SpAtk': '83', 'SpDef': '100', 'Spd': '100', 'Health': '80'}
80
80
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using a `DictReader` and passing the CSV fields as arguments.  Use `__repr__` and `__str__` to allow the class to display itself in a debug and user way:

```py
import csv
from pprint import pprint

class Pokemon:
    def __init__(self, name, type1, type2, Atk, Def, SpAtk, SpDef, Spd, Health):
        self.name = name
        self.type1 = type1
        self.type2 = type2
        self.Atk = int(Atk)  # allow int or str to be passed for initialization
        self.Def = int(Def)
        self.SpAtk = int(SpAtk)
        self.SpDef = int(SpDef)
        self.Spd = int(Spd)
        self.Health = int(Health)

    def __repr__(self):  # debug display of class instance
        return (f'Pokemon(name={self.name!r}, '
                f'type1={self.type1!r}, '
                f'type2={self.type2!r}, '
                f'Atk={self.Atk!r}, '
                f'Def={self.Def!r}, '
                f'SpAtk={self.SpAtk!r}, '
                f'SpDef={self.SpDef!r}, '
                f'Spd={self.Spd!r}, '
                f'Health={self.Health!r})')

    def __str__(self):  # pretty display of class instance
        return f'{self.name}({self.type1}/{self.type2})'

with open('Pokemon.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    Pokelist = {Pokemon(**args) for args in reader} # pass argument dictionary with **

pprint(Pokelist)
for pokemon in Pokelist:
    print(pokemon)
```

Output:

```
{Pokemon(name='Bulbasaur', type1='Grass', type2='Poison', Atk=45, Def=49, SpAtk=49, SpDef=65, Spd=65, Health=45),
 Pokemon(name='Ivysaur', type1='Grass', type2='Poison', Atk=60, Def=62, SpAtk=63, SpDef=80, Spd=80, Health=60),
 Pokemon(name='Venusaur', type1='Grass', type2='Poison', Atk=80, Def=82, SpAtk=83, SpDef=100, Spd=100, Health=80)}
Ivysaur(Grass/Poison)
Bulbasaur(Grass/Poison)
Venusaur(Grass/Poison)
```